# Java- Quitting the programme midway and resuming where you left off?

Tags: java

I am doing a java project and have several methods. Would like to know if its possible to quit the programme after the 3rd method for example and then when resuming the programme it continues from there? Any information regarding this would be helpful

THank you

Comment: can you give some insight into the context?  why are you trying to do this?  will this be required at production runtime or are you just trying to debug?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to do this? There may be a better solution.

Otherwise, it would be along the lines of saving data in some particular format (JSON, YAML, etc..) and then have a parser that could determine where the last program left off. It's somewhat vague, so it also depends on what you're attempting to "save".

Potentially could do something hacky if you ran the program with a wrapper.

Edit:

You could serialize your classes, which in turn would allow you to be able to save the fields of any objects you have, however everything you have would need to implement Serializable and be saved to a file.

So after a little bit of googling, I found that there is also the [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) library, which serializes objects to XML without needing to implement an interface. In that sense, you could serialize objects themselves, but wouldn't be able to, say, continue from the middle of a method. (Having a string you can parse to start in different locations could be one option).

Comment: Doing a mini project for my uni and if i tried to end the programme and get it to resume later from where it left of.. it would get the top marks so was wondering if that was possible.

Answer (score 2):

Not without some kind of external persistence mechanism, no.

Once the process is done, it's done.